# Method Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, methods, static, file-copying

I'm trying to display the current file being copied in a method.

Here is the code:

```
public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
    if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

    // Copy each file into it’s new directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
    {
        //Line where the error is
        lblBackupStatus.Text = "Copying " + target.FullName.ToString() + fi.Name.ToString(); 

        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is :

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Something about calling a non static property from a static method but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated! , Thanks

Comment: Which of these lines you pasted here is the compiler referring to?

Comment: My guess is that your problem is using `lblBackupStatus`. Why do you need this method to be static?

Comment: @Claudio Redi - I guess I was typing my answer at the same time as you posted yours.  Not only do we agree - it looks like we (coincidentally!) used almost exactly the same words :)

Comment: @paulsm4: yeah, lol. You explained it better, +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're probably getting the error on `"lblBackupStatus.Text = ...`.

The label belongs to a class instance (an "object"); your static CopyAll method doesn't (it's "static").

Q: Does CopyAll need to be static?  If not, see if eliminating "static" fixes the problem.

Otherwise, please post/identify the line that's giving the error.

Comment: It could quite possibly be `target` as well, since it's referenced on the first line, or even `source`.

Comment: @Joshua - it's perfectly OK to pass class instances as parameters to static methods - neither "target" or "source" should generate compile errors here.

Comment: @paulsm4, you're exactly right! I completely misread the fact this is a compile time error, not a runtime null reference exception.